# java How should implement concrete MQ GET & COMMIT/BACKOUT

Tags: ibm-mq, commit

Below I have posted a Java MQ GET routine to get info from MQ and store it on DB.
But the problem is raised when the connection is lost between GET and COMMIT.
Connection lost is interpreted as COMMIT!!! Then data is lost.

How should I implement concrete GET & COMMIT/BACKOUT model ???

```
String hostName = "192.168.163.63";
int port = 1418;
String userId = "mq";
String password = "mq";
String queueManagerName = "QueueManager1418";
String channelName = "ServerChannel";
String queueName = "TestQueue";

MQEnvironment.hostname = hostName;
MQEnvironment.port = port;
MQEnvironment.userID = userId;
MQEnvironment.password = password;
MQEnvironment.channel = channelName;
try {
    MQQueueManager qMgrIn1 = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
    int openOptionsIn1 = CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
    MQQueue queueIn1 = qMgrIn1.accessQueue(queueName, openOptionsIn1);
    MQMessage getMessage1 = new MQMessage();
    MQGetMessageOptions mqGetMessageOptions1 = new MQGetMessageOptions();
    mqGetMessageOptions1.options = CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
    queueIn1.get(getMessage1, mqGetMessageOptions1);
    String txt1 = getMessage1.readLine();
    System.out.println("get1 << " + txt1);

    //////////// make problem point like network disconnect with MQ server
    DoSaveInfo2DB();
    qMgrIn1.commit();
    if (queueIn1 != null)
        queueIn1.close();
    if (qMgrIn1 != null)
        qMgrIn1.disconnect();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("ex.getMessage() = " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

In IBM MQ documents, I noticed bellow Text

Except on z/OS batch with RRS, if a program issues the MQDISC call while there are uncommitted requests, an implicit syncpoint occurs. If the program ends abnormally, an implicit backout occurs. On z/OS, an implicit syncpoint occurs if the program ends normally without first calling MQDISC. The program is deemed to have ended normally if the TCB connected to MQ ends normally. When running under z/OS UNIX System Services and Language Environment (LE), default condition handling is invoked for abends or signals. The LE condition handlers process the error condition and the TCB ends normally. **Under these conditions MQ commits the unit of work.**

It means if application lost connection with MQ server & DB (network problem) before commit/backout, MQ automatically COMMIT them and in result we lost it !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It means if application lost connection with MQ server & DB (network
>   problem) before commit/backout, MQ automatically COMMIT them and in
>   result we lost it !!!!

Are you running your program on z/OS UNIX System Services? Because if you are not then that does not apply.  Very few companies are actually running applications on z/OS UNIX System Services - usually it is either z/OS (batch, CICS or IMS) or Linux on System Z.

If you are running on Windows or Linux or Unix (AIX, HP-UX or Solaris) then you following 2 statements apply:

- If a program issues the MQDISC call while there are uncommitted
  requests, an implicit syncpoint occurs.
- If the program ends abnormally, an implicit backout occurs.

Does that make sense?

Finally,  you are doing single phase UOW (Unit Of Work) but you should probably be doing 2 phase UOW.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I am running my app in windows . please note to position which application may exit (before commit & Disconnect)(ends abnormally) then instead backout it commit uncommitted Msg. The problem is here I want to backout automatically (may in windows not ZOS!!!). If I understand correctly , My app haven't 2nd Trans Management to implement 2 Phase UOW, I will be appreciate for any advise.

Comment: The default behavior for abnormal termination cannot be changed.  You do realize that if you do a get and the connection is lost then it is a good thing that the message is put back on the queue (so that you can process it in the future).  If you want 2 phase UOW then use the Java/MQ Extended Transactional Client (XA).